# Sequelize doesn't use the read replication

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I am try to connect to the read replication using sequelize:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', null, null, {
dialect: 'mssql',
replication: {
    read: [{
        host: 'hostRead',
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    }],
    write: {
        host: 'hostWrite',
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    }
}
});

(async () => {
    const result = (await sequelize.query('SELECT @@servername'))[0][0];
    console.log(result);
})();
```

When I run this it prints the write serverName and not the read one.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently sequelize does not parse your query type by itself so you have to explicitly specify the query type for raw sequelize queries, like so::

```
const result = (await sequelize.query('SELECT @@servername', { type: QueryTypes.SELECT }));
```